# ios view controllers keep staking in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am new to Objective C. I am working on my first app.
- It basically consists of 2 view controllers, and I use modal segue to switch between them. The main vc is a menu that loads up the 2nd vc with different attributes for each menu item.
- I noticed that the memory keeps increasing when I switch from one vc to the other. This was my attempt to solve the issue but it doesn't make a difference and it doesn't look clean.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    ViewController *me = self;
    me = nil;
}
```

What is the best practice to handle memory in a case like this?

Comment: you better show code where you switch between view controllers. and btw your viewDidDisappear method implementation is wrong. don't do that

Comment: How do you go back from the second controller to the first?

Comment: Your code snippet merely creates a new local reference to an object and then removes that local reference (effectively leaving it in the same state it was before the `viewDidDisappear` method). This code doesn't change the fact that there is obviously something else which is still maintaining a strong reference to this VC. The "set it to `nil`" technique only makes sense if you're doing that with an existing (and hopefully last) last `strong` reference to an object. You have to figure out _why_ it's not getting released (probably for reasons like those suggested by matt or implied by rdelmar).

Comment: I have figured out what was making a strong reference to my vc. I used viewWillDisappear to make that object nil, and now the memory doesn't increase.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a modal segue *in both directions*. Don't do that. You are simply creating a new view controller each time: you have view controllers piling up on top of each other. The opposite of a modal segue (which is actually `presentViewController:animated:`, after all) is not another modal segue; it is `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` (or, with some added complexity, an unwind segue).